# Show that $\left\{x\in[0,1] \rightarrow F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt : f\in C([0,1])\text{ and }||f||_\infty \leq B\right\}$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, arzela-ascoli

I am trying to show that $\mathscr{F}$ is compact, where $$\mathscr{F} = \left\{F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt\mid x \in [0,1],f\in C([0,1])  \text{ and } ||f||_\infty \leq B\right\}$$

To do so, I was planning to prove this by showing that $\mathscr{F}$ is complete and totally bounded.

I know that $\mathscr{F}$ is pointwise bounded, and pointwise equicontinuous. And, furthermore, by the Ascoli Arzel Theorem, I know that its closure is compact. I am pretty lost on how to show $\mathscr{F}$ is compact.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `\{` and `\}` to get $\{$ and $\}$ in MathJax.

Comment: Why are you using Arzela Ascoli? Is $\mathscr{F}$ not a set of numbers?

Comment: $\mathcal F$ is not a set of constants.  It is the set of all functions which can be written in the form $x \mapsto \int_0^{x}f(t)dt$ with $|f|$ bounded by $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathcal{F}$ is not closed, therefore it is not compact. It consists of differentiable functions. Let
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
-2 &0\le x\le  {1\over 2}\\
4nx-2n-2 & {1\over 2}<x\le {1\over 2}+{1\over n}\\
2 & {1\over 2}+{1\over n}<x\le 1\end{cases}$$
Then $f_n$ is continuous and $|f_n(x)|\le 2.$
Moreover $$f_n(x)\nearrow f(x)=\begin{cases} -2 & 0\le x\le {1\over 2} \\ 2 & {1\over 2}<x\le 1
\end{cases}$$ The convergence is uniform on  $0\le x\le {1\over 2}$ and on ${1\over 2}+\delta\le x\le 1$ for any fixed $0<\delta<{1\over 2}.$

For $n<m$ we have
$$|F_n(x)-F_m(x)|=\left |\int\limits_{{1\over 2}+{1\over m}}^{{1\over 2}+{1\over n}}[f_n(t)-f_m(t)]\,dt\right | \\
\le \int\limits_{{1\over 2}+{1\over m}}^{{1\over 2}+{1\over n}}[|f_n(t)|+|f_m(t)|]\,dt \le 4\left ({1\over n}-{1\over m}\right )\le {4\over n}
$$
Therefore $F_n$ satisfies the Cauchy condition, hence is uniformly convergent. Let $F$ denote the uniform limit of $F_n.$
Then for any fixed $x\in [0,1]$ we get
$$F(x)=\lim_n F_n(x)=\lim_n\int\limits_0^xf_n(t)\,dt
=\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,dt\\
=\begin{cases}-2x & 0\le x\le {1\over 2}\\
2x-2 & {1\over 2}<x\le 1
\end{cases}$$
The function $F$ does not belong to $\mathcal{F}$ because it is not differentiable at $x={1\over 2}.$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. Can you please explain what does the "$f_n(x)\nearrow f(x)$" notation means? I have never seen it.

Comment: That means $f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x)$ for any in the domain , i.e.. for $0\le x\le 1.$